# Succesfully installed "psycopg2-binary" but got ImportError: No module named psycopg2

Tags: python, pip

I was abled to install the psycopg2-binary using pip3 . So that I case use psycopg2 .

`pip3 install psycopg2-binary`

Output:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting psycopg2-binary
  Downloading psycopg2_binary-2.9.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (3.0 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.0/3.0 MB 38.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: psycopg2-binary
Successfully installed psycopg2-binary-2.9.3
```

But When I try to run `python -c "import psycopg2; print(psycopg2.__version__)"` to check if its successfully installed or not. I got this error.

````
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named psycopg2```
````

Any help ?

Thanks!

Comment: When you run `python —version` do you get the expected output? It said it wrote to the “user installation” which makes me feel that it might not be available to where you’re running the command. You should be using environments to help with that. I personally use `pipenv` but I’ve heard a good bit about `poetry`. They both use `virtualenv` or something like it under the hood.

Comment: Did you install inside or outside of virtualenv? Try to uninstall `pip3 uninstall psycopg2-binary` and install again. Also run a `pip3 check` to see if there's no broken requirements.

Comment: I install outside of virtualenv.

Comment: If you're expecting `python -c "import psycopg2; print(psycopg2.__version__)"` to work, make sure you installed the package using `python -m pip install psycopg2-binary`.